# Mongo/mongoose whole document is referenced including a ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

For a refactoring project I'm using a MongoDB with the following collections:

```
Games
Teams
Players
Goals
```

A game references two teams, and a team references two players. Both have some individual properties (like the players elo and the the team elo, there are more but I removed them for brevity).

I created the following mongoose schemas and put them in models:

```
const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  elo: Number,
  joinDate: Date
});

const teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  players: [
    { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }
  ],
  elo: Number,
});

const goalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  player: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' },
  position: String,
  color: String,
  own: Boolean,
  teamId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }
});

const gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  teamRed: ???,
  teamBlue: ???,
  winner: ???,
  teamRedScore: Number,
  teamBlueScore: Number,
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  eloChange: Number

});
```

The Player, Team and Goal objects in the database are understandable

```
{
    "_id" : "QgxP7BvnG2yxaHCPu",
    "name" : "Rachid",
    "elo" : 1447,
    "joinDate" : ISODate("2016-08-05T11:28:41.772Z")
}

{
    "_id" : "6hEZyWLuP9JHJAuj8",
    "players" : [
        "QgxP7BvnG2yxaHCPu",
        "ZkR2XEJAbXxPgiuTy"
    ],
    "teamElo" : 1631
}

{
    "_id" : "25Myqjwv5qvRBmiex",
    "player" : "QgxP7BvnG2yxaHCPu",
    "position" : "attacker",
    "color" : "red",
    "own" : false,
    "teamId" : "6hEZyWLuP9JHJAuj8"
}
```

But the Game object seems to have duplicated some of the data from the other collections.

```
{
    "_id" : "3NPo4hnq5LraBw2tZ",
    "teamRed" : {
        "_id" : "B9C3egFE4xbeKMhmW",
        "attacker" : {
            "_id" : "Bv8uDe9wSc39G3Cm6",
            "goals" : 2
        },
        "defender" : {
            "_id" : "DaKzJbzsTYtyhpwP9",
            "goals" : 2
        },
        "goals" : [
            "MW6ioYo7CCEPxLKvt",
            "YsY8cBrEsyR8CWPvW",
            "CHo9agRX8miXBysZC",
            "ct7pziiLNLcq9n3jB"
        ]
    },
    "teamBlue" : {
        "_id" : "FrjJeyT8eiKKEQj7Y",
        "attacker" : {
            "_id" : "xs2B4d3peMmTvLasp",
            "goals" : 5
        },
        "defender" : {
            "_id" : "df6kaePnj7JNAsL62",
            "goals" : 2
        },
        "goals" : [
            "h5DtWDHFoN6bJXnos",
            "cW95gPDBKuXogx3Ba",
            "dLfTKESN4FpmncQXR",
            "2dDAmPARxbtmpYDyL",
            "YaosZP7fDbJjZaACP",
            "AYrWdHchTunPusJft",
            "CZMceQ2vYBqh59JaP"
        ]
    },
    "teamRedScore" : 4,
    "teamBlueScore" : 7,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2016-10-07T15:38:08.637Z"),
    "winner" : {
        "_id" : "FrjJeyT8eiKKEQj7Y",
        "attacker" : {
            "_id" : "xs2B4d3peMmTvLasp",
            "goals" : 5
        },
        "defender" : {
            "_id" : "df6kaePnj7JNAsL62",
            "goals" : 2
        },
        "goals" : [
            "h5DtWDHFoN6bJXnos",
            "cW95gPDBKuXogx3Ba",
            "dLfTKESN4FpmncQXR",
            "2dDAmPARxbtmpYDyL",
            "YaosZP7fDbJjZaACP",
            "AYrWdHchTunPusJft",
            "CZMceQ2vYBqh59JaP"
        ]
    },
    "endDate" : ISODate("2016-10-07T15:44:13.850Z"),
    "eloChange" : 13
}
```

I'm really confused on how to query this collection. I tried to do it with the `Schema.Types.Mixed` type for the team objects in the Game, but it seems to be a mismatch, especially when I have to insert data later on. 
Referencing by ObjectId also doesn't not work, because though the ObjectId is in the data, I cannot seem to acces it. Also the team as it appears in the Game object is different from the Team as it is in the teams collection.

Is there a general approach to handle these kinds of situations? Should I make a new team-in-game schema?

Comment: Obfuscating the `ObjectId` values is not really helping the clarity of your question. If that is indeed what you are doing. The values in `_id` as presented actually look more like those generated by [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). Is this perhaps part of the migration and where the source comes from? It also looks very much like the output from `.populate()`. Please elaborate.

Comment: It is indeed a database generated by meteor (wow, good catch). I don't know what you mean by "obfuscating the ObjectId values", the output is copied directly from the following command: `db.games.find().pretty()`, would it be helpful if I query the database otherwise?

Comment: If the data has come from meteor then you need to either specify `_id` as "String" explicitly in your schema, or it would probably be best to re-write all the collections and use `ObjectId` instead of those values. Note that in the document "root", the `_id` cannot be overwritten, since that is not allowed. You would actually need to output to a new collection in order to change that. As for the other values that are "nested", you may as well remove those, and/or point them to relations if desired, since the output appears to be "pre-joined". Depends on what you want.

Comment: Put simply. Meteor has a weird way of handling `_id` values. They did this to make the generation portable to the browser. Problem is you cannot change them in existing collections. You actually need to write "new" collections to change the "root" `_id`. Your schema expects `_id` to be an `ObjectId` and it is not.

Comment: So, in this case the properties `_id` in my collections are _not_ of the mongo-type `ObjectID`?

Comment: If you are moving away from meteor it would be best to re-write "everything". So new collections and you can restructure that nested one while you are at it. If there is still some meteor code around, then you need to keep your schema compliant with what it expects. Either way it's a big job.

Comment: Ok, I understand (and I'm reconsidering some choices made until now). One last thing, converting the Player, Team and Goal seems obvious, read the values and write them with `ObjectID` in the `_id` field. Is there a way to query the Game object, and acces the `_id` fields of f.i. the `winner` field?